# Call generic function with optional parameters by passing function and parameters separately

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I want to pass a generic function as a callback to another function and then call that generic function with params.

Here's what I have right now:

```
export const prepareFunction = <
  T extends undefined | Record<string, unknown>,
  U extends () => void
>(
  queryFunction: (args: T) => { queryFn: U },
) => {
  const call = ({ data, ...params }: { data: Awaited<ReturnType<U>> } & T) => {
    queryFunction((params as unknown) as T)
  }

  return call
}

const functionWithParams = ({ param }: { param: string }) => {
  return { queryFn: () => 404 }
}

const functionWithoutParams = () => {
  return { queryFn: () => 404 }
}

const callWithParams = prepareFunction(functionWithParams)
callWithParams({ data: 404, param: 'param' })
callWithParams({ data: 404 }) // fails successfully

const callWithOutParams = prepareFunction(functionWithoutParams)
callWithOutParams({ data: 404 })
callWithOutParams({ data: 404, param: 'should fail' }) // should error that params does not exist
```

I have two questions:

1. How to prevent type casting `queryFunction((params as unknown) as T)`
2. How to make TS fail when inexisting props are passed?

Comment: So you just need to use a default type parameter and check for that then? https://tsplay.dev/mppJzm

Comment: @caTS nice, that helps, thanks! now I wonder if it's possible to type, so type casting isn't necessary.

Comment: I think using a cast here is the easiest solution.